# Link to a different <li> on another page goes only to the first item on list

Tags: html, list, html-lists

Is it possible to link to a `<li>` on another page?

I have a slider made with a list of images and i would like to link to an specific image of this slider.

I had already tryed the anchors on `<li>`. The problem is the links goes always to the first picture and not to the others with the anchors pic2 or pic3. I guess i'm doing something wrong.

Thanks

```html
<body>

<div><a href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74509233/TEMP/Untitled-2.html#pic1">link1</a></div>

<div><a href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74509233/TEMP/Untitled-2.html#pic2">link2</a></div>


<div><a href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74509233/TEMP/Untitled-2.html#pic3">link3</a></div>

</body>
```

```js
$(function () {

      // Slideshow 1
      $("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
        auto: false,
        pager: true,
        nav: true,
        speed: 500,
        maxwidth: 900,
        namespace: "centered-btns"
      });

    });

(function(c,I,B){c.fn.responsiveSlides=function(l){var a=c.extend({auto:!0,speed:500,timeout:4E3,pager:!1,nav:!1,random:!1,pause:!1,pauseControls:!0,prevText:"Previous",nextText:"Next",maxwidth:"",navContainer:"",manualControls:"",namespace:"rslides",before:c.noop,after:c.noop},l);return this.each(function(){B++;var f=c(this),s,r,t,m,p,q,n=0,e=f.children(),C=e.size(),h=parseFloat(a.speed),D=parseFloat(a.timeout),u=parseFloat(a.maxwidth),g=a.namespace,d=g+B,E=g+"_nav "+d+"_nav",v=g+"_here",j=d+"_on",
w=d+"_s",k=c("<ul class='"+g+"_tabs "+d+"_tabs' />"),x={"float":"left",position:"relative",opacity:1,zIndex:2},y={"float":"none",position:"absolute",opacity:0,zIndex:1},F=function(){var b=(document.body||document.documentElement).style,a="transition";if("string"===typeof b[a])return!0;s=["Moz","Webkit","Khtml","O","ms"];var a=a.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+a.substr(1),c;for(c=0;c<s.length;c++)if("string"===typeof b[s[c]+a])return!0;return!1}(),z=function(b){a.before(b);F?(e.removeClass(j).css(y).eq(b).addClass(j).css(x),
n=b,setTimeout(function(){a.after(b)},h)):e.stop().fadeOut(h,function(){c(this).removeClass(j).css(y).css("opacity",1)}).eq(b).fadeIn(h,function(){c(this).addClass(j).css(x);a.after(b);n=b})};a.random&&(e.sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5}),f.empty().append(e));e.each(function(a){this.id=w+a});f.addClass(g+" "+d);l&&l.maxwidth&&f.css("max-width",u);e.hide().css(y).eq(0).addClass(j).css(x).show();F&&e.show().css({"-webkit-transition":"opacity "+h+"ms ease-in-out","-moz-transition":"opacity "+
h+"ms ease-in-out","-o-transition":"opacity "+h+"ms ease-in-out",transition:"opacity "+h+"ms ease-in-out"});if(1<e.size()){if(D<h+100)return;if(a.pager&&!a.manualControls){var A=[];e.each(function(a){a+=1;A+="<li><a href='#' class='"+w+a+"'>"+a+"</a></li>"});k.append(A);l.navContainer?c(a.navContainer).append(k):f.after(k)}a.manualControls&&(k=c(a.manualControls),k.addClass(g+"_tabs "+d+"_tabs"));(a.pager||a.manualControls)&&k.find("li").each(function(a){c(this).addClass(w+(a+1))});if(a.pager||a.manualControls)q=
k.find("a"),r=function(a){q.closest("li").removeClass(v).eq(a).addClass(v)};a.auto&&(t=function(){p=setInterval(function(){e.stop(!0,!0);var b=n+1<C?n+1:0;(a.pager||a.manualControls)&&r(b);z(b)},D)},t());m=function(){a.auto&&(clearInterval(p),t())};a.pause&&f.hover(function(){clearInterval(p)},function(){m()});if(a.pager||a.manualControls)q.bind("click",function(b){b.preventDefault();a.pauseControls||m();b=q.index(this);n===b||c("."+j).queue("fx").length||(r(b),z(b))}).eq(0).closest("li").addClass(v),
a.pauseControls&&q.hover(function(){clearInterval(p)},function(){m()});if(a.nav){g="<a href='#' class='"+E+" prev'>"+a.prevText+"</a><a href='#' class='"+E+" next'>"+a.nextText+"</a>";l.navContainer?c(a.navContainer).append(g):f.after(g);var d=c("."+d+"_nav"),G=d.filter(".prev");d.bind("click",function(b){b.preventDefault();b=c("."+j);if(!b.queue("fx").length){var d=e.index(b);b=d-1;d=d+1<C?n+1:0;z(c(this)[0]===G[0]?b:d);if(a.pager||a.manualControls)r(c(this)[0]===G[0]?b:d);a.pauseControls||m()}});
a.pauseControls&&d.hover(function(){clearInterval(p)},function(){m()})}}if("undefined"===typeof document.body.style.maxWidth&&l.maxwidth){var H=function(){f.css("width","100%");f.width()>u&&f.css("width",u)};H();c(I).bind("resize",function(){H()})}})}})(jQuery,this,0);
```

```css
html, body, div, ul {
background: transparent;
border: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: top;
list-style:none;
list-style-type: none;
}
.rslides {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.rslides_container {
  /*margin-bottom: 50px;*/
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  }

.centered-btns_nav {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  top: 30px;
  right: 95px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
 background-image:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74509233/TEMP/BF.gif);
 background-size:cover;
  }

.centered-btns_nav:active {
  opacity: 0;
  }

.centered-btns_nav.next {
  left: auto;
  background-position: right top;
  right: 50px;
  }


.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rslides_container">
<ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
        <li id="pic1"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74509233/TEMP/Pic1.jpg" alt="pic1"></li>
        <li id="pic2"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74509233/TEMP/Pic2.jpg" alt="pic2"></li>
        <li id="pic3"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74509233/TEMP/Pic3.jpg" alt="pic3"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Give an id to the `<li>` element and use `URL#id`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and see how and what to ask here. HINT: Post effort and code. In your case, if the LI has a UNIQUE ID add it to the URL `#idOfLi`

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: I had already tryed the anchors on < l i >. The problem is the links goes always to the first picture and not to the others with the anchors pic2 or pic3. I guess i'm doing something wrong. The code is added at the question, the script is from responsiveslides.com. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With an achor you can target an elements ID e.g. `#mycustli` on the current or another page, simply append it to the target Url.

### Example:

On one page:

```
<a href="www.example.com/page2#mycustli" title="">Go to the awesome li</a>
```

On the target page:

```
<li id="mycustli">There we are. Look at that astonishing element.</li>
```

Comment: I had already try anchors on <li>, the problem is the link goes to the page but no to the anchors. I insert the code on the question, clicking on links always appears the first image.